# Работа с модулями в GIT

Tags: git, git-submodule

Есть внешний репозиторий в котором реализован базовый функционал по работе с бд, в дальнейшем буду называть его `DAL` — слой доступа к данным).

Создаю новый проект, подключаю `DAL` в качестве модуля:

```
git submodule add ../Projects/DataAccessLayer DAL
```

В текущем проекте мне необходимо его немного *допилить напильником*, данные изменения уникальны в рамках текущего проекта, в основном репозиторий `DAL` они мне не нужны.

Как правильно организовать/сделать такую работу?

**UPD.:**

На текущий момент я построил свою работу так:

1. Создаю новую ветку: `git checkout -b НоваяВетка`;
2. Делаю необходимые мне изменения: добавляю новые классы, реорганизую, ну и т.п.;
3. Индексирую изменения, комичу: `git add ...` -> `git commit -m 'Здесь какой то текст'`;
4. Вливаю изменения в главную ветку: `git checkout master` -> `git merge НоваяВетка`;
5. Повторяю с начала списка по мере рефакторинга, добавления нового функционала;

**UPD2**

```
Master v.0.1
   | \
   |  \
   |   \
   |    \
   |   v.0.1
   |    /
   |  dal
   |  /
   | /
Master
```

т.е. я подключаю модуль в ветке `dal`, улучшения модуля `dal` делаем в ветках которые пойдут от `dal`

я правильно понял?

Comment: вариантов два, первый сделать ветвление и пилить уже нужную ветку, второй вариант напилить екстеншенов в проекте и не трогать библиотеку вообще

Comment: Вообще, отличный вопрос. Эта проблема часто возникает при работе с субмодулями. А потом еще и pull нужно будет как-то делать, чтобы обновить его — например, если сделаете какие-то фиксы общие.

Comment: вроде правильно понял. Потренируйтесь на каком-нибудь пробном репозитории.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1.

Подумайте, можно ли допиливание осуществить за счет конфигурации? Например, вынести разные константы в отдельный конфиг. В составе субмодуля у вас будет один конфиг с дефолтными значениями, а в конкретном проекте — второй, в котором некоторые из значений могут быть переопределены. Тогда необходимость вносить изменения в субмодуль исчезнет.

Вариант 2.

Сделайте в субмодуле новую ветку, специфическую для этого проекта. Вносите изменения в нее. Если вы внесете какие-то общие изменения в DAL и захотите обновить их в репозитории, то вам нужно будет обновить master, а потом сделать rebase ваших изменений на новый последний коммит.

Было:

```
master    feature
        Y
        |
    C   X
    | /
    B
    | 
    A
```

Станет:

```
master    feature
        Y'
        |
        X'
      /
    C
    |
    B
    | 
    A
```